# Access to fetch at 'blahblahblah' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch an API but I keep encountering the same error over and over, and I have checked the server and there's no problem from there, I was wondering if you can help me with it?
This is the code that I wrote:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class FetchData extends React.Component {

    async componentDidMount() {
        var myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("Authorization", "sth");

        var requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: myHeaders,
            redirect: 'follow'
        };
        fetch("blahblahblah", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => console.log(result))
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));

    }

    render() {
        return <div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is solved in several ways:

**First -** 
Your url add this address at the end

```
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/YOUR URL
```

**Second -**

see this doc [Proxying API Requests in Development](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development)

**Other ways -**

[3 Ways to Fix the CORS Error — and How the Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header Works](https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to whitelist your domain inside your server. the easiest way is to use the npm package [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) for your cors configuration

Answer (score 0):

have you know what is the meaning CORS ?it means (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) see this link to understand it [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS]
your backend must accept CORS and when you send credentials in the request you must allow credentials also